# How to bulk add disabled-password users?

Tags: useradd, shadow

Doing:

```
# newusers
username::1002:1002::/home/username:/bin/bash
^D
No password supplied
No password supplied
No password supplied
newusers: (user username) pam_chauthtok() failed, error:
Authentication token manipulation error
newusers: (line 1, user username) password not changed
```

adds the user with no password (with hash "!" in `/etc/shadow`).

Doing:

```
# newusers
username:*:1002:1002::/home/username:/bin/bash
^D
```

adds the user with a password of "*" (with some hash in `/etc/shadow`).

However, what I need is to add that "username" user with a hash of "*" in `/etc/shadow`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the password field blank.  `newusers` will complain repeatedly about 'No password supplied' and being unable to change the password, but the users will be created with `!` (i.e. invalid password) in the shadow password field.

```
username::1002:1002::/home/username:/bin/bash
```

instead of:

```
username:*:1002:1002::/home/username:/bin/bash
```

For example:

```
# echo "username::10000:10000::/home/username:/bin/bash" | newusers 
No password supplied
No password supplied
No password supplied
newusers: (user username) pam_chauthtok() failed, error:
Authentication token manipulation error
newusers: (line 1, user username) password not changed

# tail -1 /etc/passwd
username:x:10000:10000::/home/username:/bin/bash

# tail -1 /etc/shadow
username:!:16713:0:99999:7:::
```

Comment: But, is `!` the same as `*`?

Comment: yes.  they're both invalid passwords.   see `man shadow` and search for 'encrypted password': `If the password field contains some string that is not a valid result of crypt(3), for instance ! or *, the user will not be able to use a unix password to log in (but the user may log in the system by other means).`

Comment: Doesn't work with rhel6 and rhel7, any pointers for those ?

Answer (score 0):

After adding your batch of users, you can unlock each user with the following command:

```
usermod -p <username> '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do note that if you send '*' or '!' as password you may end up having all yours users set with that specific password. The points mentioned by @cas are valid when considering the contents of `/etc/shadow` and not the content of the passwords themselves. Given that by default `newusers` will encrypt the password, this will not work.

The way to enforce that the password is disabled is to force no encryption:

```
echo 'username:*:16713:0:99999:7:::' > users
```

Then disable encryption:

```
newusers -c NONE users
```

The best way to confirm this is by checking the generated `/etc/shadow`:

```
tail /etc/shadow
```